# Drupal 7, can't login after downloading to local machine

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I downloaded a Drupal 7 site from a production server, and now I am trying to set it up on my laptop. Not only does /user/login not work, /?q=user doesn't direct me to the user login screen either. I get a 'page not found' error. Anyone ever run into this issue? I am using WAMPserver 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

1.Is it MOD_REWRITE MODULE turned on on you Apache?
2.The second thing I would check is .htaccess just download a default one to be sure> https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was being redirected to the 'https' login site instead of the 'http' one. Just had to delete the 'securelogin' and 'securepages' modules from the /sites/all/modules folder.